# Logic proof - Boxes inside a table

Tags: tables, border, cell

I want to create a table as below:

[image]

But I only came up with the table code, with no clue of how to add the two boxes.

```
  \begin{table}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{lll}
        1. & $(\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha)))$ & Assumption \\
        2. & $\alpha$ & Assumption \\
        3. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$  & $\lor i$: 2  \\
        4. & $\bot$ & $\bot i$: 1,3  \\
        5. & $(\lnot \alpha)$ & $\lnot i$, 2-4 \\
        6. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lor i$: 5 \\
        7. & $\bot$ &  $\bot i$: 1,6 \\
        8. & $(\lnot (\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))))$ & $\lnot i$:1-7\\
        9. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lnot \lnot e$: 8 \\
      \end{tabular}
      \label{tab:mytable}
  \end{table}
```

Any idea of how to add the boxes?

Comment: LaTeX for Logicians is your friend: https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `logicproof` package was designed with the precise aim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{logicproof}{2}
\begin{subproof}
  (\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))) & Assumption    \\
  \begin{subproof}
    \alpha                             & Assumption    \\
    (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))       & $\lor$i: 2    \\
    \bot                               & $\bot$i: 1,3
  \end{subproof}
  (\lnot \alpha)                       & $\lnot$i, 2-4 \\
  (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))         & $\lor$i: 5    \\
  \bot                                 & $\bot$i: 1,6
\end{subproof}
(\lnot (\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha)))) 
                                       & $\lnot$i: 1-7 \\
(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))           & $\lnot\lnot$e: 8
\end{logicproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One method is using `tikzmark` library. In the following MWE, the `shift` values are appropriate for the standard `article` document class. For other classes, you may have to adjust them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    1.\tikzmark{a1} & $(\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha)))$ & Assumption \\
    2.\tikzmark{a3} & $\alpha$ & Assumption \\
    3. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$  & $\lor i$: 2  \\
    4.\tikzmark{a4} & $\bot$ & $\bot i$: 1,3  \\
    5. & $(\lnot \alpha)$ & $\lnot i$, 2-4 \\
    6. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lor i$: 5 \\
    7.\tikzmark{a2} & $\bot$ &  $\bot i$: 1,6 \\
    8. & $(\lnot (\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))))$ & $\lnot i$:1-7\\
    9. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lnot \lnot e$: 8 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw ([shift={(6cm, 1em)}]pic cs:a1) rectangle ([shift={(5pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:a2);
  \draw ([shift={(5.8cm, 0.8em)}]pic cs:a3) rectangle ([shift={(10pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:a4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the package `tabularray`.

- `vline{2} = {1}{1-8}{solid}`, draw a first verical line column 2, row 1 to 8.
- `vline{2} = {2}{2-4}{red,solid},`, draw a second verical line column 2, row 2 to 4.
- `leftpos=0,rightpos=0` only touches the first vline.

The red color to better visualize the code concerned.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}
    {
        column{1}={cmd=\mycnta .},
        %
        vline{2} = {1}{1-8}{solid},
        vline{2} = {2}{2-4}{red,solid},
        vline{4} = {1}{2-4}{red,solid},
        vline{4} = {2}{1-8}{solid},
        %
        hline{1,9} = {2-4}{solid},
        hline{2,5} = {2-4}{red,leftpos=0,rightpos=0,solid},
    }
& $(\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha)))$ & Assumption \\
& $\alpha$ & Assumption \\
& $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$  & $\lor i$: 2  \\
& $\bot$ & $\bot i$: 1,3  \\
& $(\lnot \alpha)$ & $\lnot i$, 2-4 \\
& $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lor i$: 5 \\
& $\bot$ &  $\bot i$: 1,6 \\
& $(\lnot (\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))))$ & $\lnot i$:1-7\\
& $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lnot \lnot e$: 8 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the frames by using the PGF/Tikz nodes creates by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{lll}
    1. & $(\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha)))$ & Assumption \\
    2. & $\alpha$ & Assumption \\
    3. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$  & $\lor i$: 2  \\
    4. & $\bot$ & $\bot i$: 1,3  \\
    5. & $(\lnot \alpha)$ & $\lnot i$, 2-4 \\
    6. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lor i$: 5 \\
    7. & $\bot$ &  $\bot i$: 1,6 \\
    8. & $(\lnot (\lnot (\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))))$ & $\lnot i$:1-7\\
    9. & $(\alpha \lor (\lnot \alpha))$ & $\lnot \lnot e$: 8 \\
  \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (1-|2) rectangle (8-|last) ;
      \draw ([xshift=1mm]2-|2) rectangle ([xshift=-1mm]5-|last) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]